# Compute the value of $\iint |x+y|\, dxdy$, given the $x=-1$ to $x=1$ and $y=-1$ to $y=1$.

Tags: calculus, integration

I have no clue how to go about solving it. I tried to split up the given double integral in two parts that is from $-1$ to $0$ and $0$ to $1$, but my answer came out to be $2$ and the given  answer is $8/3$. I would like to know where i am going wrong. thanks

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Hint : By symmetry $\iint|x+y|dxdy=2 \iint_D(x+y)dxdy$ then make a change of variable $u=x+y \in (0,2)$ and $v=y \in (0,1)$

Comment: Thank you! I will try that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split as follows

$$\int_{-1}^1\int_{-1}^1|x+y|dxdy
=- \int_{-1}^1\int_{-1}^{-x}(x+y)dy dx + \int_{-1}^1\int_{-x}^1(x+y)dy dx
= \frac43+\frac43=\frac83
$$

Comment: Hi! Thanks for taking your time and answering my query. I know this might sound dumb, but can you please tell me as to why do we have to take limits from -1 to x and from -x to 1. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @NatashaJ - note that $x+y=0$ is the boundary for $|x+y|$ to take different signs. Thus, $y= -x $ is the limit for $dy$

Comment: OK! Thanks I got it now!